# each function in javascript for new elements

Tags: javascript

I have a page with infinite scroll that appends new elements as the user scrolls down. ".product-variation" is one such element. I want to remove the first option of all newly arriving elements. The code below does the job but I think it goes up and down the DOM a bit too much - retarding performance in the process. Is there a better and more efficient way of removing the first option of just the newly arriving elements?

The first option of all newly arriving element is always '' and that's what I am trying to remove.

```
jq(".product-variations").each(function(){
        var fresh_variant = jq(this).find("option:nth-child(1)").val();
        if(fresh_variant == '')
            {
                jq(this).find("option:nth-child(1)").remove();
            }

        jq(this).trigger('change');
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd put a flag :

```
jq(".product-variations:not([data-set])").each(function(){
        var fresh_variant = jq(this).find("option:nth-child(1)").val();
        if(fresh_variant == '')
            {
                jq(this).find("option:nth-child(1)").remove();
            }

        jq(this).trigger('change');
        jq(this).attr('data-set',1);

    });
```

So now , when you add item , you set a flag "set".

Next time , you scan only new ones.(who don't have the flag)

Oh  , and BTW here is a better version of your code :

```
jq(".product-variations:not([data-set])").each(function(){
       var $this=jq(this);
       var $opt=$this.find("option:nth-child(1)");
        var fresh_variant = $opt.val();
        if(fresh_variant == '')
            {
                $opt.remove();
            }

        $this.trigger('change');
        $this.attr('data-set','whatever');

    });
```